# cutting with ffmpeg results in few seconds of black screen, how do i fix this?

Tags: ffmpeg

i'm using this command to cut a segment from a video from command line

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss %2 -t %3 %~n1_cut%~x1
```

and i call it like

```
cut.bat video.mp4 001:23:45:678 10
```

and as expected i get a video_cut.mp4 with 10 seconds of the original video, problem is that few seconds of the resulting file is black screen with audio, why does this happen and how do i fix it?

Comment: %~n1_cut%~x1 what does this part of the command mean?

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus `%~n1` expands %1 to a file Name, or if only a path is present (with no trailing backslash) - the last folder in that path and `%~x1` expands %1 to a file eXtension only - .txt source:https://superuser.com/questions/224416/what-do-df0-and-df1-mean-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 15):

Most videos use codecs which perform temporal compression, so a specified cutpoint may rely on frames before (and after) that cutpoint to be correctly decoded. So, when you use ffmpeg to trim videos and use `copy` mode, ffmpeg has to include all frames before and after the trimmed segment which are needed to decode the segment correctly.

So, you have two options, use copy mode but set a switch which will allow all players to correctly play these files

```
ffmpeg -ss %2 -t %3 -i %1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero %~n1_cut%~x1
```

(this will likely result in output that starts before your cutpoint)

or re-encode the streams

```
ffmpeg -ss %2 -t %3 -i %1 %~n1_cut%~x1
```

Comment: Although re-encoding is slower, it will produce better results, because with the other solution the video might be longer then what was specified in the `-t` option.

Comment: @Gyan What does `%` do? I tried searching https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html but I can't find the usage.

Comment: As your answer suggested I used both `-ss` and `-t` before `-i` and it worked, before, I only put `-ss` before `-i` and `-t` was after it so it didn't work.

Comment: So, no way to use `-codec copy` but not blank video at start of trimmed video? If I have to, I will, but the trimmed video loses quality. The first option starts before cutpoint and that includes copyright music which I want to cut out.

Answer (score 11):

https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/pull/13

When I run ffmpeg with the arguments in this order -i ... -ss ... -t ..., it produces a video file that has no video for a few initial seconds. (as far as I can understand this is because it doesn't seek to a keyframe?)

If I change the order to -ss ... -i ... -t ..., then the resulting cut videos play properly.

Comment: I tried `-ss` before `-i` but it didn't work on my mp4 file.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Merely changed the order of parameters. ffmpeg version 3.2.12-1~deb9u1

Comment: Actually, this just moves the blank duration to the end of the video

Comment: Changing parameter order worked well for me.

Comment: It works only partially plus it produces much larger chunks. I thinks is really depending on the codec used. I have a thermal camera footage (5min, 27MB) that I want to split into 30 chunks. With the **i-ss-t** order I get 30 pieces I get 15MB with most chunks smaller than 600KB but most containing black frames for several seconds (each chunk is 10sec long). With the **ss-i-t** order I get almost 10MB per chunk with still some seconds of black footage for the first file.

Comment: The changing of the order of input file and `-ss` command worked for me! Very strange!!!

Comment: this is really weird.. changing the order worked for me. But the file size sky rocketed by a few xx.